# Python Reflection and callable objects

Tags: python, oop, class, reflection

I have a two part question.

```
>>> class One(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> class Two(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> def digest(constr):
...     c = apply(constr)
...     print c.__class__.__name__
...     print constr.__class__.__name__
... 
>>> digest(Two)
Two
type
```

How would one create object 'Two'? Neither constr() or c() work; and it seems that apply turns it into a type.

What happens when you pass a class rather and an instance into a method?

Comment: I think these functions like apply are deprecated or not considered a part of modern usage. See the pointers in my reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would one create object 'Two'?
>   Neither constr() or c() work; and it
>   seems that apply  turns it into a
>   type.

The above comment was made in regards to this code:

```
>>> def digest(constr):
...     c = apply(constr)
...     print c.__class__.__name__
...     print constr.__class__.__name__
```

`apply` (deprecated: see @pyfunc's answer) certainly does not turn the class `Two` into a type: It already is one.

```
>>> class Two(object): pass
... 
>>> type(Two)
<type 'type'>
```

Classes are first class objects: they're instances of `type`. This makes sense if you look at the next example.

```
>>> two = Two()
>>> type(two)
<class '__main__.Two'>
```

You can see that a class very clearly functions as a type because it can be returned from `type`. Here's another example.

```
>>> Three = type('Three', (Two, ), {'foo': 'bar'})
>>> type(Three)
<type 'type'>
>>> three = Three()
>>> type(three)
<class '__main__.Three'>
```

You can see that `type` is a class that can be instantiated. Its constructor takes three arguments: the name of the class, a tuple of base classes and a dictionary containing the class attributes. It returns a new `type` aka class.

As to your final question,

> What happens when you pass a class
>   rather and an instance into a method?

You're going to have to be more specific. Classes are just instances of `type` and so are first class objects. Asking what happens if I pass a class into a method is like asking what happens if I pass an integer into a method: It depends entirely on what the method is expecting.

Comment: *“The appropriate variable name would be cls”* – Uh, why? It's a variable, you can name it whatever you want.

Comment: Aaron, the second question you addressed(passing a class into a method) was really just a silly question to make sure that nothing is happening behind the scenes.(.net background. :)  You answered it with saying that it's the same as it would be passing an int or string. Thanks!

Comment: @poke `def __init__(this, foo): this._foo = foo + 1`.  It's a well know fact that one should name a variable by what it is and, failing that, by convention. Classes seem to get names `cls`.

Comment: @poke on second thought, a factory function could be passed in. Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

Classes are high level objects, so you can simply pass them like this:

```
def createMyClass ( myClass ):
    obj = myClass()
    return obj

class A ( object ):
    pass

>>> x = createMyClass( A )
>>> type( x )
<class '__main__.A'>
```

Comment: How is this different from calling x = myClass(). May be I am missing something here.

Comment: @pyfunc: Of course in this example it is not different; the point is that you can pass classes around to functions which then do the instantiation (and any arbitrary action, like presetting some values) and simply return the object. Because obviously that is what OP was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Just another one example:

```
def InstanceFactory(classname):
   cls = globals()[classname]
   return cls() 

class A(object):
   def start(self):
       print "a.start"

class B(object):
   def start(self):
        print "b.start"

InstanceFactory("A").start()
InstanceFactory("B").start()
```

If the class belongs to another module:

```
def InstanceFactory(modulename, classname):
    if '.' in modulename:
        raise ValueError, "can't handle dotted modules yet"
    mod = __import__(modulename)
    cls = getattr(mod, classname]
    return cls()
```

Comment: Demas, I've heard of globals in python for a while but never really nailed it down to the wire. What does globals() accomplish in this?

Comment: Also, you answered my next google question. How to import from another module. Thanks!

Comment: @jbcurtin, go to google. That's a highly nonstandard way of importing something. It's useful when you only know that name of what you're importing at runtime. Learn standard `import` first.

Comment: globals() a dictionary representing the current global symbol table.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused though. Wasn't apply() deprecated since 2.3

- http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0290/

We don't need this any more.

```
apply(f, args, kwds)  -->  f(*args, **kwds)
```

Others have been moved / considered deprecated in modern usage:

1. buffer()
2. coerce()
3. and intern()

Simply use : Classname() to create an object.